# how can I embed link inside the svg

Tags: html, hyperlink

I created an icon and want to make it clickable with link.

I use this code for icon. added href but it didn't work. idk where to add it.

Comment: <div style = "position:fixed; right:150px; bottom:10px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;" style="position: fixed; left: 24px; top: 24px;" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z"/></svg>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href` is not a standard attribute (like `style` or `id`), it applies to the `a` tag

Why not wrap your SVG in a link (`a`) tag?

You can then configure the link to do things like open in a new window.
[See more on the `a` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a style="position:fixed; right:150px; bottom:10px;" href="https://example.com">
  <svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;" style="position: fixed; left: 24px; top: 24px;" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z"/></svg>
</a>
```